# Which is the difference between Calabash-ios and Calabash-cucumber?

Tags: calabash

What is the difference between Calabash-ios and Calabash-cucumber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calabash-ios and calabash-cucumber both refer to the same gem, so there is no difference.

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios

the reason the gem is called calabash-cucumber is historical - in the beginning there was no calabash-android gem.

i believe the plan is change the gem name to calabash-ios in version 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think its not only because of the name but another reason, in case they are just the same.

Comment: I am a calabash-cucumber and calabash-android gem maintainer.  We've talked about changing the name of calabash-cucumber to calabash-ios in version 1.0.